# Footer is not fixed while using ScrollView in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, scrollview, footer, fixed

while I am using scrollview in jquerymobile, footer is not fixed in mobile.
How to fix the footer while I am using scrollview.
I tried `data-position:fixed` and other methods are not working.